# can't execute the sqlite query (react native)

Tags: sqlite, react-native

i want to execute this query that return the service_name by service_id

i dont know if the syntax of query is correct or not , because it dosent change the value of service_name

here is my code :

```
    getServiceNameById = (service_id) => {

       var service_name = 'passport';
       db.transaction((tx) => {
        var query = 'select * from service_details where service_id ='+service_id;

        tx.executeSql(query, [], (tx, results) => {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            if (len > 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    let row = results.rows.item(i);
                    service_name = row.service_name;
                }

            }

            console.log(service_name);  // -> it show in console  the initial value of service_name : passport 
            return(service_name); 


        });
    });


        }
```

any help please

Comment: Your question is unclear. You are running a `SELECT` query. Why do you expect a changed service name? Does your statement work if you run it manually in the SQLite console?

Comment: my question is clear i just want to know if the syntax of my query correct or not :)  and in return statement cannot return any thing , btw tn console.log it retun the correct result that i want ,, but my problem now in return statement

Comment: Then please edit the title of your question. Currently it is "can't execute the sqlite query (react native)", but if you can execute the query, your question must be something else.